# Membership fee based on custom field

Tags: civimember

Seeking advice on the best practice way to implement membership fees based on the custom field which contains organisation income. i.e. Membership fee would be 1% of income for type 'A' contact.

I understand custom development is likely to be involved, so would it be best to create a module & which hooks or classes to override? Something that is maintainable through releases without constant code changes would be good.

Comment: In short, a membership rate calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [membershipTypeValues hook](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_membershipTypeValues) and implement that in an extension.