# Set value of one field based on another field

Tags: civirules, fields

I've seen a couple of answers to similar questions (e.g. [How do I set the value of external_id to be the same as a custom field?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-external-id-to-be-the-same-as-a-custom-field) and [Membership fee based on custom field](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/membership-fee-based-on-custom-field)).

What I want to do is change the content of a field from www.fubar.com/id= to www.fubar.com/id=[CONTENT OF FIELD]
I thought this was doable with CiviRules, but it appears there is no option to change the contents of a field based on the value of another field change (I can do other things based on a field value change).

Is this an area where I need to look into custom development? Or am I missing the bleeding obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own action for CiviRules to update the field you want. You can find guidelines on creating CiviRules actions [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to set aside some time to look into this.